# Passing array to function, to multiply every value of the array by 10

Tags: c

This program is to multiply every value of array by 10 using a function. I am getting a lot of errors.
Can I take size in for loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
mult(int arr[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr*=10;
    }
    return arr;
}
int main()
{
    int j[];
    printf("enter the all ten values to multiply by 10");
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        scanf("%d");
   j[] = mult(j);
   printf("%d",&j);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the real code? why doesn't `mult()` have a return type?

Comment: `arr*=10;` <- Which element of the array is `arr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete code learn the differences and correct your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void mult(int *arr,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      arr[i]*=10;
}

int main()
{
  int size=10;
  int j[size],i;
  printf("enter the all ten values to multiply by 10\n");
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d",j+i);
  mult(j,size);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("%d ",j[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: will you explain one thing please why you scanned j+i?

Comment: Here j is the name of the array, but also contains the address of the first entry of the array (it's a pointer to the first entry in the array). When you add integer number to a pointer, pointer arithmetic is applied and the adress of the i-th entry in the array is computed. This is the same as &j[i] - the adress of the entry j[i].

Answer (score 2):

`int j[];` You're creating an array wrongly (in this context). You have to specify its size. Eg.: `int j[256];`

`for(j=0;j<size;j++) scanf("%d");` What's `size`? how can you increment an array?? You're using `scanf` wrongly. You should do `for(int s=0;s<size;s++) scanf("%d",&j[s]);`.

`j[] = mult(j);` is wrong again. You should create another array and copy values there.

`printf("%d",&j);` you don't need `&` here, remove it. You'd better use `"%d\n"` to print each number on its own line.

`mult(int arr[])` function declared wrongly. You must specify a type your function returns. You may need to use `int *mult(...)` instead and `return &arr[0];`

`arr*=10;` what're you trying to achieve with this? Completely wrong, you're multiplying the address here.

---

**Read the docs, please!** Your code *doesn't make any sense, please learn C first, then try to code.*

Moreover, you'll need pointers here, pay attention to them. I'd advise you to write *Hello World* program first to just understand the basics. Mr. Kernighan and Mr. Ritchie will help you too.

---

**Note**: I may have missed some mistakes here as there are *too many* of them. Please correct me if so.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell `mult()` what is the size of the array, and the array you are passing will be modified in `mult()` so you don't need to return a value.

```
mult(j, size);
```

and your `mult()` function

```
void mult(int *arr, size_t size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr[i] *= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr*=10` is incorrect. You would want `arr[i]*=10` at least.

Comment: You can't return a pointer to automatic local variable. BTW, downvote is not mine.

Comment: can you you correct the whole code? i am noob in c just started 5 days earlier